# Python GTK: Scrollable Grid with clickable images

Tags: python, gtk

I'm writing an python program (gui in gtk) (linux btw.)
I want to have a (scrollable) grid of images that are clickable like buttons.

I'm planning to have 3 images per line, show 2 lines and then scroll vertically through the rest.

I don't really know which elements to use, a Gtk.Grid, a Gtk.table or something else ?
Should I use a image and make it clickable or should I use a Gtk.Button and make it look like an image ?

Would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. The widgets I'd use are:

```
Gtk.ScrolledWindow
  Gtk.Grid
    Gtk.Button
    Gtk.Button
    ...
    Gtk.Button
```

I'm not really aware of the advantages of using `Gtk.Grid` over `Gtk.Table`, but I see it's the default widget now in glade, so I'd stick to the defaults.

Regarding using a `Gtk.Image` or `Gtk.Button`, it's documented how to display an image in a button, but I'd say isn't so easy to make an image clickable because that's not an event supported out of the box by image widgets. Hence, the safest approach in my opinion is to use buttons.

Answer (score 0):

GTK4 now have a GridView/ListView.
*also they have example of "FileBrowser":
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/demos/gtk-demo/listview_filebrowser.c
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/demos/gtk-demo/listview_filebrowser.ui